# How can I parse records from a text file to an array?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

here is a snippet of the file,

```
Year 1
mandatory
COM137,Mathematics for Computing,20,2
COM140,Computer Technologies,1-2,20
COM147,Introduction to databases,1-2,20
Year 2
optional
COM606 ..... etc
```

I want from this an array that reads

COM317,Mathematics for Computing,20,2,M,Year1

COM140,Computer Technologies,1-2,20,M,Year1

this is the layout of each element in the array that i want, but i have no idea how to do it, so the app reads the document see's year 1 stores that in current year then reads mandatory stores that as M in a variable, then i want to add that to an array, then when it sees year 2 it starts again year 2 added to the array element instead.. this is the what i have attempted so far

```
  Dim arrModules As String()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("datasource.txt")
    Dim line = sr.ReadLine() ' get each line and store it 
    Dim currentYear As Integer
    Dim moduleStats As String = ""
    Dim modArray As String()


    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        If line.Contains("Year") Then
            currentYear = line
        ElseIf line.Contains("mandatory") Then
            moduleStats = "M"
        ElseIf line.Contains("optional") Then
            moduleStats = "O"
        ElseIf line.Contains("COM") Then
            modArray = sr.ReadLine.Split(",")

            MsgBox(modArray)
        End If
        count += 1
        sr.ReadLine()
    End While
    End
```

// in here is where i am having the problem i don't know how to get all the information i need into one specific array element within an array.. i want to get the year and the module status added to the end of an array element

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and explain exactly what you have problems with.

Comment: il edit my post now with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This being Visual Basic, you could make room for the last two elements this way:

```
Dim i As Integer = modArray.Length
ReDim Preserve modArray((i - 1) + 2)

modArray(i) = moduleStats
modArray(i + 1) = currentYear.ToString()
```

Comment: this is gonna sound really amateur but that's what i am really, um how can i check the values in the array then?.. i'm trying to use messageBox but nothing is appearing, I'm assuming i should put the message box within the loop or should i?

Comment: Neither MessageBox.Show() nor MsgBox() will display a String array. You could instead try this: MsgBox(String.Join(",",modArray))

Comment: this appears to be entering an infinite loop somewhere, when I press a button on the GUI it does nothing and the GUI freezes until i press the stop button, therefore it does not display the message box..

Comment: Inside the While loop, make sure you read in the next line with "line = sr.ReadLine()" and not just "sr.ReadLine()".

Comment: ok this works to a certain extend, its displaying the message box, and adding year1 to the end however i need year 1 to change once it reaches year 2 in the text, i thought it would do this with the  If line.Contains("Year") Then
            currentYear = line

Comment: If you really meant for currentYear to be an Integer, then you'll need to parse out the number from the line (which is in the form of "Year ###").

Comment: i see whats happening here, it appears to be reading a line and skipping a line the reading the next, which means in some cases its not even reading the line with year in it

Answer (score 0):

Copy the result from Split to a new, larger array and add the additional info.

```
Dim modArray As String() = {"A", "B", "C"}
Dim finalArray As String() = New String(modArray.Length + 1) {}
Array.Copy(modArray, finalArray, modArray.Length)
finalArray(finalArray.Length - 2) = "M"
finalArray(finalArray.Length - 1) = "Year1"
```

Or you can simply use

```
ReDim Preserve modArray(modArray.Length+2)
modArray(modArray.Length - 2) = "M"
modArray(modArray.Length - 1) = "Year1"
```

Comment: this is adding year and M to different elements in the array.. ? this is what i want {COM317,Mathematics for Computing,20,2,M,Year1} year and M added to the end of an existing array element? anyway that can be tweaked to support this?

Comment: My first example creates a new larger array, the second increases the size of the existing array. Both add two values at the end. Take the second example with Redim Preserve. It does what you want.